# MVC 5 Facebook Authentication - Forcing user to re-authenticate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, owin

We're using the OWIN Facebook authentication provider to allow users to authenticate however each time a user attempts to user Facebook to authenticate against our application, we want to force the user to re-authenticate with Facebook. Right now, if a user has already authenticated against Facebook, the user isn't required to log in to Facebook when they attempt to authenticate against our application.

How can we force the Facebook Authentication Provider to require the user to login to Facebook again?

Comment: So a user goes to your site and logs in using facebook, and the problem is they don't re-authenticate through facebook on subsequent requests? How often should they re-authenticate? Every request?

Comment: The facebook owin middleware is used to initially authenticate with facebook, after that your application maintains a cookie that says "this user is already logged in" so it no longer needs to go to facebook to authenticate. You can control the lifetime of your application cookie, make it last only for the current browser session, which will force the user to login again the next time they visit the site

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding what you are asking... If you are asking how to force the user to have to goto facebook and manually type in their username and password everytime they try to authenticate with your application, then I don't understand the reasoning. If they are already signed in to facebook, then they are authenticated... why force them to sign in again?

Comment: I should elaborate, we don't actually want them to sign into our application with Facebook. We're aggregating all their Facebook data to display within our tool for pages they administer. There is a one-time hook-up process for them to authenticate with our app so we can grab an access token. The challenge is that we want the user to be conscious of what credentials they're entering.

Comment: I'm not sure what your implementation is, but if you try to authenticate with facebook, and they are already signed in to facebook and have authorized your app, you can't force them to be signed out of facebook so that they have to manually enter their username and password again

Comment: It's convenient to stay logged in with facebook, but how about the scenario of shared browser - the user who logged in to your site is completely unaware that they are still logged in to facebook when they log off your site. Another user comes along, clicks the facebook login option and they are into the web site with the original users login.